# How do I write a a generic function composer and apply generic tuple extraction functions (first, second) in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here:

```
const first  = <A>([a]: [A, unknown]) => a

const second  = <B>([,b]: [unknown, B]) => b

const tuple = <A>(a: A) => <B>(b: B): [A, B] => [a, b]

type F<A, B> = (a: A) => B

const compose = <B, C>(f: F<B, C>) => <A>(g: F<A, B>) => (a: A) =>
  f(g(a));

const t = tuple(tuple(1)(true))("x")

const x = second(first(t))

const composeSecond = compose(second) // fails

const secondAfterFirst = composeSecond(first)

const y = secondAfterFirst(t)
```

It fails `compose(second)` with:

> const second: ([, b]: [unknown, B]) => B Argument of type '([,
>   b]: [unknown, B]) => B' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'F'.   Types of parameters '__0' and 'a' are
>   incompatible.
>       Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '[unknown, unknown]'.

Comment: Sorry for my basic question, but on the function `<A>([a]: [A, unknown]) => a`, what does this mean `[]:[]`? Does this function have only 1 argument? I don't understand the signature. Also, I don't understand this; `[,b]`

Comment: It is basically destructuring the function arguments. So it could also be:
`<A>(tuple: [A, unknown]) => tuple[0]`

Comment: The same applies to `[,b]`.

Comment: Maybe it's [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30727)?  The [pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215) enabling anything like this does mention the algorithm for inferring higher-order types isn't perfect.  Not sure if this rises to the level of an answer, though, or if there's some way to rewrite your code to fix it

Comment: You can [lead the compiler by the nose](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//?ts=Nightly#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgSwE7RjAvDAPAQQHwAUA2gIYC6AXDETgDQwCuYA1mCAO5hkCUGeMJALAAoUJFgQApmIAmaTFgBChIrQBGlak1Ycw9RTz4w1IsaigMADgBtJGbPgIkqOXun5LCaqou5Ua+mRGpPQaANwipuCooAC2liBS9kowkgAeUJJgMhACYACe9ADChHBUBN4wvkZFbh6OAOblzjCuRtXuMAQiaC04In4wRUZwBA1O3NwRwlHiMLCYFjaSBEu2BACM3KtIDJKTBABEaYdTs6hp9lKyBIgoUKuT0+ewcQlSAMrS4DJUuPqEJpdPp1LQsNicQKgpwuUGKexvRIra4-M6iaISSzSBAkawIABekhkADFkNA-gAVQiWEjIfxEbQQvQwClkeiM3SGToM8G6eis+x3aDTMwSb7ZHBwTJIUn3BEgeJIr43CBY4A4vGEklkqBol4wfJXcUySXS2XQR7TIA), not sure if that suffices.

Comment: Thanks, not really though. I was really looking for solution that with just type inference. I think I've hit a limit of the system here though.

Comment: `const compose = <B, C>(f: F<B, C>) => <A>(g: F<A, B>) => (a: A) =>
  f(g(a))` means something different than `const compose = <A, B, C>(f: (b: B) => C) => (g: (a: A) => B) => (a: A) => f(g(a))`. You want the latter.

Comment: As for the other parts of your code, I think a better starting point would be `type Tuple<A,B> = [A, B]` followed by `const first = <A,B>([a, _]: Tuple<A,B>): A => a` and `const second = <A,B>([_, b]: Tuple<A,B>): B => b` and `const tuple = <A,B>(a: A, b: B): Tuple<A,B> => [a, b]`. This still has the same issue with `compose`, but I think this demonstrates more effective TypeScript.

Comment: @user633183 My defenition for compose is curried. Either way the output would be the same. What do you mean by _more effectivie_? I don't think it affects how it works. Maybe how it reads.

Comment: @chautelly look closely, both definitions are curried but that has no impact on the polymorphic parameters. You can think of `<A, B, C>` as the parameters needed for the entire closure, regardless of whether its curried or not. Your first definition actually means something different: the inner `B` in `g: F<A,B>` effectively shadows the outer `B` in `f: F<B,C>`. In the second definition, the `B` parameter is declared _once_ but used in `f: ...` and `g: ...`.

Comment: (cont'd) Your types for `first` and `second` don't really make sense. They take a tuple as input, which is necessarily polymorphic, `<A,B>`. But you write `const first  = <A>([a]: [A, unknown]) => a` and `const second  = <B>([,b]: [unknown, B]) => b` each with only _one_ parameter. You write `second` with `<B>` that is no different than `<A>` or `<Foo>`, it is only _one_ parameter. By writing `const first = <A,B>([a, _]: Tuple<A,B>): A => a` we communicate that `first` is polymorphic in _two_ parameters, takes a value of type `Tuple<A,B>` and returns the a value of type `A`.

Comment: (cont'd) Usually you will want to name your types, like `Tuple` here, but TypeScript has syntax for tuples specifically. As a shortcut you can write: `const first = <A,B>([a, _]: [A,B]): A => a` and `const second = <A,B>([_, b]: [A,B]): B => b` and `const tuple = <A,B>(a: A, b: B): [A,B] => [a, b]`. Avoid `unknown`; there's nothing unknown about `<A,B>`.

Comment: You could argue that using `unknown` is safer as it prevents the data from being used in the function implementation.